# Printing Types in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I have some very simple logic in OCaml:

```
let load filename =
  let file = get_file filename in
  let len = String.length file in
  Printf.printf "%a\n" file
  ()
```

(The `get_file` is a function I wrote.) As you can see from this snippet, I want to print the contents of `file` just to understand what it's returning. I used `%a` because one of the OCaml tutorials said you should do that for this kind of thing. When I say "this kind of thing", I mean a channel and for that I'll show what my `get_file` function looks like:

```
let get_file filename =
  let channel = open_in_bin filename in
  let length = in_channel_length channel in
  let file = really_input_string channel length in
  close_in channel;
  file
```

Okay, so referring to my code in the `load` method, I get the following error:

```
6 |   Printf.printf "%a\n" file
                           ^^^^
Error: This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type
         out_channel -> 'a -> unit
```

So I think "Okay, it's a type string -- since that's what the message is telling me -- so I should do that in my printf." So I change my printf to this:

```
Printf.printf "%s\n" file
```

Yet now the error is:

```
6 |   Printf.printf "%s\n" file
                    ^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type
         ('a -> 'b, out_channel, unit, unit, unit, 'a -> 'b)
         CamlinternalFormatBasics.fmt
       but an expression was expected of type
         ('a -> 'b, out_channel, unit, unit, unit, unit)
         CamlinternalFormatBasics.fmt
       Type 'a -> 'b is not compatible with type unit
```

I have no idea how you are supposed to make something out of that obtuse error message, given the error message I originally started with when I used `%a`.

So then I thought maybe the `file` was the wrong thing to try since it's this channel thing and maybe I'm missing something. So instead I try to print out the `len` variable, which should just be a straight up integer. I change my printf to this:

```
Printf.printf "%d\n" len
```

And I get another useless (to me) error message:

```
6 |   Printf.printf "%d\n" len
                    ^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type
         ('a -> 'b, out_channel, unit, unit, unit, 'a -> 'b)
         CamlinternalFormatBasics.fmt
       but an expression was expected of type
         ('a -> 'b, out_channel, unit, unit, unit, unit)
         CamlinternalFormatBasics.fmt
       Type 'a -> 'b is not compatible with type unit
```

I tried switching the printf for `len` to the `%a` just to see what it reported and I got this:

```
6 |   Printf.printf "%a\n" len
                           ^^^
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type
         out_channel -> 'a -> unit
```

Yeah, it has a type int. Which is what I originally tried to print! So this is a mirror situation of the first. The one error message tells me the variable is a specific type. I then try to print that specific type and I get the longer, but much less helpful (to me), error message.

I cannot find a decent OCaml tutorial that just takes you through this simple sort of example of using diagnostic print statements to determine what the language is doing, hence posting here to find out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It looks like you're missing a semicolon on your `Printf.printf` line, so the `()` argument is being passed into `Printf.printf`. Is that intentional? It seems like a bug.

Comment: Ooookay, that's embarrassing. That appears to be what it was. Or, rather, it's sort of embarrassing. I'm still not clear on when I do and don't have to use semicolons and I'm not sure why the error message was so different each time, given that apparently it _was_ the semicolon. But I guess what you're saying indicates that: the `()` was being passed in.

Comment: I think you should treat `expr;` as equivalent to `let () = expr in`; i.e. you can use a semicolon whenever you have an expression that evaluates to `unit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the error message is that the `Printf` function family are very flexible, which translates to very complex error message when the number of arguments send to the function is more than expected.

In your first case,

```
Printf.printf "%a\n" file ()
```

`Printf` receives the right number of arguments, because the specifier `%a` requires two arguments: the custom printer and the data that needs to be printed. Thus, you got a type error on `file`, because  `file` is not a printing function.

However, in the second case,

```
Printf.printf "%s\n" file ()
```

the number of arguments is wrong.

The type checker then tries to reconcile the expected number of argument with the actual number of argument. In its exploration, it deduces that the application will be fine if

```
Printf.printf "%s\n" file
```

returned a function. In particular,

```
Printf.kprintf (fun _ () -> ()) "%s\n" file
```

would be fine.
This is what the error message is trying to say. If we focus on the last type
parameter,

```
Error: This expression has type
         (..., 'a -> 'b) fmt
       but an expression was expected of type
         (..., unit) fmt
       Type 'a -> 'b is not compatible with type unit
```

The first line tells us that the number of arguments compared to the format arguments required us to return a function of type `'a -> 'b` at the end of the printing.
However, the last line tell us that the function `Printf.printf` can only returns a value of type `unit` at the end of the printing.
Since `unit` and `'a -> 'b` are not the same type, this an error.